# Using "new" keyword in Objective-C++ -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, objective-c++

I am somehow experiencing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to dynamically allocate a c++ class object at runtime using the `new`keyword on a `.mm` file with the compiler set to objective-c++. Any help or direction with this would be greatly appreciated! I had zero problems when I ran this game in its native c++ project file.

```
#import "GameCode.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "GameKitHelper.h"
#import "CardView.h"
#import "MainFunctions.hpp"




@interface GameCode ()<GameKitHelperDelegate>
{
MainFunctions Main;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *cardContainerView;

@end

@implementation GameCode

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerAuthenticated)
                                                 name:LocalPlayerIsAuthenticated object:nil];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

Pack *pack = new Pack;// delete after game

//Pack *pack = Pack_Maker();
//Pack *pack = [Pack new];
//Pack *pack = [[Pack alloc] init];
```

Default Pack constructor

```
Pack::Pack()
    : next(0)
{

 for (int i = 0; i < PACK_SIZE ; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_SUITS ; j++)
    {
        //K=7 TO k =0
        for(int k = 0; k < NUM_RANKS; k++)
        {
            cards[i] = Card(RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[k], SUIT_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[j]);
            cards[i].get_value();
        i++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Suits in order from lowest suit to highest suit.
constexpr const char* const SUIT_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[] = {
  Card::SUIT_SPADES,
  Card::SUIT_HEARTS,
  Card::SUIT_CLUBS,
  Card::SUIT_DIAMONDS
};
```

Card constructor used

```
Card::Card(const std::string &rank_in, const std::string &suit_in)
: rank(rank_in), suit(suit_in) {}
```

I even tried making a function to dynamically allocate it for me, didn't work. The bad access error seems like it occurs in the default card assignment operator `Card::operator=` so I tried to create a custom assignment operator but the issue continued.

```
/*
Card & Card::operator=(const Card &that)
{
this->rank = that.get_rank();
this->suit = that.get_suit();
    return *this;
}
*/
```

Below is a thread trace of the error from `Card::operator=` to the fatal error in `char_traits<char>::assign:`

```
`Card::operator=:
    0x1090682a0 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x1090682a1 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x1090682a4 <+4>:   subq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x1090682a8 <+8>:   movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x1090682ac <+12>:  movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x1090682b0 <+16>:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
    0x1090682b4 <+20>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rcx
    0x1090682b8 <+24>:  movl   (%rcx), %edx
    0x1090682ba <+26>:  movl   %edx, (%rax)
    0x1090682bc <+28>:  movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x1090682bf <+31>:  addq   $0x8, %rcx
    0x1090682c6 <+38>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
    0x1090682ca <+42>:  addq   $0x8, %rsi
    0x1090682d1 <+49>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x1090682d4 <+52>:  movq   %rax, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x1090682d8 <+56>:  callq  0x1090688f0               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator= at string:2303
->  0x1090682dd <+61>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rcx
```

```
`std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=:
    0x1090688f0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x1090688f1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x1090688f4 <+4>:  subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x1090688f8 <+8>:  movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x1090688fc <+12>: movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x109068900 <+16>: movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
    0x109068904 <+20>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
    0x109068908 <+24>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10906890b <+27>: movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x10906890f <+31>: callq  0x109068920               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign at string:2291
->  0x109068914 <+36>: movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
```

```
`std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign:
    0x109068920 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x109068921 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x109068924 <+4>:   subq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x109068928 <+8>:   movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x10906892c <+12>:  movq   %rsi, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x109068930 <+16>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rax
    0x109068934 <+20>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x109068937 <+23>:  movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x10906893b <+27>:  callq  0x109068990               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__clear_and_shrink at string:3819
->  0x109068940 <+32>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
```

```
`std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__clear_and_shrink:
    0x109068990 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x109068991 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x109068994 <+4>:   subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x109068998 <+8>:   movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x10906899c <+12>:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
    0x1090689a0 <+16>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1090689a3 <+19>:  movq   %rax, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x1090689a7 <+23>:  callq  0x109068ac0               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::clear at string:3061
->  0x1090689ac <+28>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rdi
```

```
`std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::clear:
    0x109068ac0 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x109068ac1 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x109068ac4 <+4>:   subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x109068ac8 <+8>:   movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x109068acc <+12>:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
    0x109068ad0 <+16>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x109068ad3 <+19>:  movq   %rax, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x109068ad7 <+23>:  callq  0x109068ce0               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__invalidate_all_iterators at string:1684
    0x109068adc <+28>:  jmp    0x109068ae1               ; <+33> at string
    0x109068ae1 <+33>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x109068ae5 <+37>:  callq  0x109068b60               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__is_long at string:1420
    0x109068aea <+42>:  testb  $0x1, %al
    0x109068aec <+44>:  jne    0x109068af7               ; <+55> at string
    0x109068af2 <+50>:  jmp    0x109068b22               ; <+98> at string
    0x109068af7 <+55>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x109068afb <+59>:  callq  0x109068bf0               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__get_long_pointer at string:1499
    0x109068b00 <+64>:  movb   $0x0, -0x9(%rbp)
    0x109068b04 <+68>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x109068b07 <+71>:  leaq   -0x9(%rbp), %rsi
    0x109068b0b <+75>:  callq  0x109068cf0               ; std::__1::char_traits<char>::assign at __string:208
->  0x109068b10 <+80>:  xorl   %ecx, %ecx
```

```
`std::__1::char_traits<char>::assign:
    0x109068cf0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x109068cf1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x109068cf4 <+4>:  movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x109068cf8 <+8>:  movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x109068cfc <+12>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rax
    0x109068d00 <+16>: movb   (%rax), %cl
    0x109068d02 <+18>: movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
->  0x109068d06 <+22>: movb   %cl, (%rax)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided the declaration for `cards` and the limit constants, but this loop looks very fishy to me:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < PACK_SIZE ; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_SUITS ; j++)
    {
        //K=7 TO k =0
        for(int k = 0; k < NUM_RANKS; k++)
        {
            cards[i] = Card(RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[k], SUIT_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[j]);
            cards[i].get_value();
        i++;
        }
    }
  }
```

I suspect `i` runs out of range of your `cards` array. You're incrementing `i` in both the outermost loop's iteration expression and inside the innermost loop's body.

Assuming `NUM_SUITS` is 4 and `NUM_RANKS` is 13 as in a standard deck of cards, this code will assign `cards[0]` through `cards[51]` on the first iteration of the outermost loop, then skip `cards[52]` and assign `cards[53]` to `cards[104]`, skip `cards[105]`, and so on.

I expect the dimensions of `cards` are probably a multiple of `NUM_SUITS * NUM_RANKS` such as 156. In that example, you'd overrun the array by 2 while the inner loops try to assign to the non-existent `cards[156]` and `cards[157]`.

I suggest perhaps changing the outermost loop to `while (i < PACK_SIZE)` and putting some `assert`s in your code to ensure the array dimensions and running index match your expectations:

```
  int i = 0;
  while (i < PACK_SIZE)
  {
    assert(i + NUM_SUITS * NUM_RANKS <= cards.size());
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_SUITS ; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < NUM_RANKS; k++)
        {
            cards[i] = Card(RANK_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[k], SUIT_NAMES_BY_WEIGHT[j]);
            cards[i].get_value();
            i++;
        }
    }
  }
  assert(i <= cards.size());
```

Needless to say, if this code was taken verbatim from a pure C++ project, the error existed there too.

Comment: Switched over to the pure C++ project, set a breakpoint, annnnnnnnd sure enough cards were skipped. Thanks again!